# Handle many IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a character counter for all input fields in a form. This is my script, for when I focus on the input field, when I leave it, and when I finish pressing a key:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#in1").keyup(function () {
        $("#count1").text(50 - this.value.length);
    });
    $("#in1").focus(function () {
        $("#countainer1").show();
        $("#count1").text(50 - this.value.length);
    });
    $("#in1").blur(function () {
        $("#countainer1").hide();
    });
});
```

You can see it working here:
http://jsfiddle.net/UQFD6/12/

The question is:

**Do I have to generate the script for each ID?**

I mean, the code will be the same, but applied to different IDs: `#input1` shows `#countainer1` and modifies `#count1`, then `#input2` with `#countainer2` and `#count2`, and so on.

I thought of using classes instead of ids, but when it shows the container, it will show every container of that class, instead of only the one for the field I'm writing in.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can use a class instead of `#in1`, e.g. add the *in* class to elements you currently give the id *in1*, *in2*, etc.

```
$(".in").keyup(function () {
```

You can use an attribute e.g. `data-id=1` on elements that you need to select that are associated with your current `#in1`, e.g.

```
var id = $(this).data('id');
$(".count[id='" + id + "']").text(...);
```

Comment: I'll try it Eric, if I get it to work I'll update my post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[id^=in]').each(function(){ // all inputs whose id starts with "in"
       var i = this.id.slice(2); // finds "32" from "in32"
        $(this).keyup(function () {
            $("#count"+i).text(50 - this.value.length);
        }).focus(function () { // let's chain
            $("#countainer"+i).show();
            $("#count"+i).text(50 - this.value.length);
        }).blur(function () {
            $("#countainer"+i).hide();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This is more or less what I wanted to do, but I didn't know how. I'll try it, thanks!

Comment: I see you deleted you message, but I answer you anyway:

No, don't get me wrong, I'm not saying I don't like your code or anything, it's just that I don't know what "keyup" or "[id^=in]" do, for example. I am very novice in JQuery and Javacript. Thanks!

Comment: [the "starts with" selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/). `keyup` was in your code, I didn't add it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with classes instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".in").keyup(function () {
        $(this).siblings(".count").text(50 - this.value.length);
    }).focus(function () {
        $(".countainer").show();
        $(this).siblings(".count").text(50 - this.value.length);
    }).blur(function () {
        $(this).siblings(".countainer").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't know what siblings does, but I'll find out! Thanks!

Comment: `.siblings()` is for finding elems at same level, like in your case you have `input` and then just below it your div which shows the text.